# Data not being pulled from a plugin onto the word press page?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, plugins

I'm new to web development and I have a problem with one of our sites. 
I didn't build it and it's using a custom theme which I know nothing about. know a little bit of code but not enough understand that.
anyway, there's a place on the homepage that's supposed to pull in the latest events from an event plugin but it's not.

here is the link to the website. 
https://themadeeproject.com

and a link to the plugin I'm trying to pull the data from.
https://theeventscalendar.com

a pic of the what it's pulling right now

[image]

any help or Suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: any specific error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to pull only one event?
Maybe there is an option in the backend for pulling a certain number of events.